# One-dimensional numerical integration in R with values > 2^1024?

Tags: r, precision, numerical-integration

I am trying to use R to evaluate a definite integral of a univariate function that contains an expression of the form `exp(exp(x))`, with the upper bound on `x` exceeding 100. When using the base `integrate()` function, I get the error "non-finite function value" in this case, as the values involved exceed the largest number that can be represented using R's double precision arithmetic (2^1024 or ~10^300).

The `Brobdingnag` package is very helpful when it comes to dealing with very large numbers, but `integrate()` coerces all values to doubles internally, so if I try to define the integrand as, say, `exp(as.brob(exp(x)))` (an expression that can be evaluated), I just get a different error ("evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length"). I also tried using the `integrateR()` function from the `Rmpfr` package, but on my set-up (package version 0.8-40, R version 4.1.0), even just attempting to run the example code given in the documentation (`integrateR(exp, mpfr(0,200), 1, rel.tol=1e-25, verbose=TRUE)`) would abort my R session.

Is there an alternative to R's `integrate()` that can deal with the very large numbers arising in the integrand?

**Edit from 2021-09-15**: Minimal reproducible example of an attempted solution added below:

```
if(!require("Brobdingnag") {install.packages("Brobdingnag")}
library(Brobdingnag)

f <- function(x) {
  term1 <- 0.8361913 * exp(0.1516063*x) * exp(0.1788979 * exp(8.577809*x))
  term2 <- 0.9512496 * exp(8.577809*x) + 0.04875068
  return(term1 * term2)
}

log_f <- function(x) {
  x <- as.brob(x)
  term1 <- 0.1788979 * (exp(8.577809*x) - 1) + 0.1516063*x 
  term2 <- log(0.9512496 * exp(8.577809*x) + 0.04875068)
  return(term1 + term2)
}

u <- 131.6
log_S <- log(u) + log_f(u)    # +exp(1127.1)
integrate(function(x) {as.double(exp(log_f(x) - log_S))}, lower = 0, upper = u)
# 0 with absolute error < 0
```

Answer (score 3):

A strategy that will probably work:

Pick a scaling value `S` that will prevent overflow of the full integral. For example, if the function is increasing in `x` (and positive) and we integrate from 0 to `u`, the integral is bounded by `u*max(f(x)) = u*f(u)`. (If `f` is non-monotonic, you just have to have some reasonable way of guessing the order of magnitude of its maximum.) Then scale your integrand by this value:

```r
log_S <- log(u) + log_f(u)
i0 <- integrate(function(x) { exp(log_f(x) - log_S) }, from = 0, to u)
log_result <- log(i0) + u*log_S
```

Where `log_f()` is the log of the original function (e.g. `exp(x)` if `f` is `exp(exp(x))`.

(If this `log_S` is too big, you can shrink it; the idea is to pick a scaling function that prevents the full integral from overflowing but doesn't allow the largest values of the integrand to overflow.)

Either (1) all the values are of large magnitude, in which case they won't be lost by underflow, or (2) the values that are *not* of large magnitude (and are thus lost by underflow) do not make up an important component of the integral.

A clever analyst could certainly come up with a function that will break this scheme (e.g. a function with a Dirac delta function or other narrow, tall spike in it), but this should be OK for a large class of 'not too nasty' functions.

You could also do a brute-force Riemann sum with `Brobdingnag` or `Rmpfr`  or [`matrixStats::logSumExp`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/matrixStats/versions/0.60.1/topics/logSumExp) (i.e., pick a sensible `dx` and compute `sum(f(x_i)*dx)`), but if you wanted fancy stuff like adaptive choice of `dx` you'd have to re-implement it yourself ...

Comment: Thank you for this clever workaround; that looks like it might help. Would you just mind clarifying your notation a little bit? Does `log_f(x)` refer to the logarithm of the original integrand? (Fortunately, the function I'm interested can be expressed as a product of several simpler functions, so its logarithm is easy enough to obtain analytically – the general case might be more difficult.) Also, do I understand correctly that this will only work if the integrand is monotonically increasing on [0, `u`]?

Comment: I have now implemented your solution, and although it may work in most cases, it doesn't solve my problem. Part of it is my fault: my `f(x)` included `exp(exp(A*x))` rather than just `exp(exp(x))`, and for some `A`, even `log_f(x)` exceeded 2^1024. I got around this by using `Brobdingnag` and coercing the result to a double (following your logic that the values lost by underflow don't contribute much to the integral), but ran into a more fundamental issue: `f(x)` increases so rapidly that this makes `log_f(x) - log_S` equal to 0 for any `x != u`, so the log of the integral is just `u*log_S`.